# How to extract links with xpath expression

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

This is the html markup I want to extract links from:

```html
<div id="target">
    <a href="https://www.chotosite.com">chotosite</a>
    <a href="https://www.bit2lead.com">bit2lead</a>
</div>
```

This is my xpath expression and scrapy code

```py
links = response.xpath("//div[@id='target']/a/@href")
for link in links:
    print(link)
```

What I expect to find is

```
https://www.chotosite.com
https://www.bit2lead.com
```

But what I found on console:

```
<Selector xpath="//div[@id='target']/a/@href" data='https://www.chotosite.com'>
<Selector xpath="//div[@id='target']/a/@href" data='https://www.bit2lead.com'>
```

How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: links = xpath("//div[@id='target']/a/@href").extract()

Comment: That helped. thank you..

Comment: please accept my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope its help you.

```
In [18]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<div id="target">
        ...:     <a href="https://www.chotosite.com">chotosite</a>
        ...:         <a href="https://www.bit2lead.com">bit2lead</a>
        ...:         </div>""")
    


In [20]: [link.xpath('@href').extract_first() for link in selector.xpath('//div/a')]
Out[20]: ['https://www.chotosite.com', 'https://www.bit2lead.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your desired results:

```py
links = response.xpath("//div[@id='target']/a/@href").extract()
```

`.extract()` will create an array

Use `response.xpath` not `xpath` alone

now you can loop through your links

```py
for link in links:
    print(link)
```